# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" (calling Razor page from View)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using C# ASP.NET MVC 5.

**ProductService (View)**

```
using Shop.Application.ViewModels;
using Shop.Domain.Interfaces;
using System.Linq;

namespace Shop.Application.Services
{
    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        private IProductRepository _productRepository;
        public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            _productRepository = productRepository;
        }

        public ProductViewModel GetProdutcts() =>
            new ProductViewModel()
            {
                Product = _productRepository.GetProducts().ToList(),
            };
    }
}
```

**ProductViewModel**

```
using Shop.Domain.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Shop.Application.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**IProductService**

```
using Shop.Application.ViewModels;

namespace Shop.Application.Services
{
    public interface IProductService
    {
        ProductViewModel GetProdutcts();
    }
}
```

**ProductController**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Shop.Application.Services;

namespace Shop.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private IProductService _productService;

        public ProductsController(IProductService productService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
        }

        public IActionResult Index() =>
            View(_productService.GetProdutcts());
    }
}
```

**Products Page + bug: (click in link to see the image)**
[Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE59g.png)

## MY DOUBT: how to fix it?

**what i already tried, but didn't work**

- add the ProductViewModel in dataSet
- instantiate the View's return model
- Create the page using Visual studio scaffold
- Create a if like people told here: [Object reference not set to an instance of an object on partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646154/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-on-partial-view)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE59g.png) (post your code as text) there's a `@page` directive inside your Razor.

You appear to be mixing "controllers with views" and "Razor Pages". Your controller is never called. Your page is a Razor Page. Your page's `OnGet()` method in the codebehind (Index.cshtml.cs) needs to populate your model.

Comment: worked, i changed my code to load model in IndeModel (Index.cshtml.cs file)